# Do we need to create two AMI's for master and core in EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-ami

I need to create a AWS EMR cluster for spark job with one master and 4 core nodes with auto scaling. I need to have different Instance types for master and core with Ubuntu 16.0 installed on it. So do I need to create two AMI's for this master and slave.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon EMR has its own library of AMIs. You can select the AMI **version** when launching the cluster.

You can create a custom AMI, but it must be based on **Amazon Linux**.

See: [Using a Custom AMI - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-custom-ami.html)

If you wish to launch a Hadoop cluster with your own Ubuntu AMI, you cannot use the Amazon EMR service. You will need to launch and configure it yourself on Amazon EC2 instances.